# Issue in Mvc Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have made on for loop as:

```
 @foreach (var ObjCompanyContact in (List<BalCentral.DataModel.VisaCaseDestinationCountryEmploymentContact>)ViewData["VisaCaseDestinationCountryEmployment"])
                                   { 
                                       <table class="email_phone" style="width:100%">
                                              <thead>
                                                 <tr>
                                                   <th></th>
                                                   <th><label class="control-label-superscript">Primary?</label></th>
                                                   <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                               </thead>

                                      <tr>
                                        <td>@*<input type="text" id="Text22" class="span4" placeholder="Email Address" value="test@test.com">*@

                                          @Html.TextBox("Email",ObjCompanyContact.Email,new {@class="span4",@placeholder="Email Address"})
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="Email"/></td>
                                        <td><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" id="Text21" class="span4" placeholder="Email Address" value="test@test.com"></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                        <td><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr style="background-color: #F0F0F0 ">
                                        <td colspan="3" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px; "><label class="help-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px"">Add Email Address:</label></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr style="background-color: #F0F0F0 ">
                                        <td><input type="text" id="Text23" class="span4" placeholder="Add Email Address"></td>
                                        <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></td>
                                      </tr>

                                      </table>  

                                   }
```

The issue id its saying for loop is missing its closing tags.After checking several times i couldn't able to find out the issue.Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the html in your for block inside <text></text> ?

Comment: Yes... While wrapping table tag got closed completely. but the issue remains the same

Comment: You have an extra " in line '<td colspan="3" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px; "><label class="help-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px"">Add Email Address:</label></td>' that may have causeed the parser to go off.

Comment: You also need to add /> for all your unbalanced input tag if your code does not still work

Comment: @shakib Sir i have tried what have u said to do. but the issue remains the same. i tried closing the only tr tag on foreach loop then only issue get resolved but i want to closed the whole table into it

Comment: @shakib is right. `margin-bottom: 0px"">Add Email Address:` should be `margin-bottom: 0px">Add Email Address:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the following line from

```
<td colspan="3" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px; "><label class="help-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px"">Add Email Address:</label></td>
```

to

```
            <td colspan="3" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;">
            <label class="help-block" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
                Add Email Address:</label>
        </td>
```

Formats well, and fixes your issue, checked at runtime too.